# Casting mock using generic type

Tags: c#, generics, casting, nunit, moq

Apologies, this is a long description!

I have a generic class which represents a given value.

```
public class ValueClass<T>
{
    public object Value { get { return this._value; } }
    protected T _value;

    public ValueClass(T value)
    {
        this._value = value;
    }

    public string Print()
    {
        return ((T)this.Value).ToString();
    }
}
```

This can be exercised as shown:

```
[TestCase(1, "1")]
[TestCase(2, "2")]
public void Works(int value, string expected)
{
    ValueClass<int> uut = new ValueClass<int>(value);

    string ret = uut.Print();

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, ret);
}
```

This works fine for types such as `int`, but if I want to use a custom class then this fails. For example for the type `ICustomType`, the ToString method should be called.

```
public interface ICustomType
{
    string ToString();
}
```

So the following test fails, where `ICustomType` is being mocked:

```
[TestCase("1")]
[TestCase("2")]
public void Fails(string expected)
{
    Mock<ICustomType> customTypeStub = new Mock<ICustomType>();
    customTypeStub.Setup(x => x.ToString()).Returns(expected);

    ValueClass<ICustomType> uut = new ValueClass<ICustomType>(customTypeStub.Object);

    string ret = uut.Print();

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, ret);
}
```

(Additional diagnostic lines added below - casting to specific type works, but not to type T)

```
public class ValueClass<T>
{
    public object Value { get { return this._value; } }
    protected T _value;

    public ValueClass(T value)
    {
        this._value = value;
    }

    public string Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this.Value.ToString() : " + this.Value.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("((ICustomType)this.Value).ToString() : " + ((ICustomType)this.Value).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("((T)this.Value).ToString() : " + ((T)this.Value).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("typeof(T) : " + typeof(T));
        Console.WriteLine("(typeof(T) == typeof(ICustomType)) : " + (typeof(T) == typeof(ICustomType)));

        return ((T)this.Value).ToString();
    }
}
```

Diagnostic information below:

```
***** tests.Types.Fails("1")
this.Value.ToString() : Castle.Proxies.ICustomTypeProxy
((T)this.Value).ToString() : Castle.Proxies.ICustomTypeProxy
typeof(T) : Types.ICustomType
(typeof(T) == typeof(ICustomType)) : True
***** tests.Types.Fails("2")
this.Value.ToString() : Castle.Proxies.ICustomTypeProxy
((T)this.Value).ToString() : Castle.Proxies.ICustomTypeProxy
typeof(T) : Types.ICustomType
(typeof(T) == typeof(ICustomType)) : True
```

So as far as I can tell, Moq is correctly mocking the ToString method. This works fine when being cast manually to the fixed type. However when relying on the generic type T to define the casting, this fails.

Note that the reason I must keep `Value` as type `object` rather than type `T` is that ValueClass implements a non-generic interface - value must be accessible but the type cannot be defined at interface level.
Can anyone explain this behaviour??

Comment: Why are you reading the property, and casting, when you already have the value in a private field of the right type?

Comment: Good question - the reason is that the work would actually be performed in another class - which knows `T` but is accessing the value through the interface (as `object` type). The code shown was just refactored code to keep it simple - there are another few classes involved in this part of my actual system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the compiler does not know that you intend to give it an interface that instructs it to use a *different* ToString method than the one that every object has.

The only thing the compiler knows about `T` is that it is *some type*. The compiler will compile that method at compile time with the knowledge it has then, and even if you later give it an interface that would in effect tell it to use a different `ToString` method, it won't use it because it has already compiled the method for *all* types, and that compilation used the one provided by `System.Object`.

So, you can't do it this way.

You *could* instruct your `ValueClass` to only support types for `T` that implement your interface but I suspect that's not what you want.

Here's how the Print method was compiled:

```
ValueClass`1.Print:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        15 00 00 0A 
IL_0006:  unbox.any   05 00 00 1B 
IL_000B:  stloc.0     // CS$0$0000
IL_000C:  ldloca.s    00 // CS$0$0000
IL_000E:  constrained. 05 00 00 1B 
IL_0014:  callvirt    System.Object.ToString
IL_0019:  ret
```

As you can see, it was compiled to call directly down into `System.Object.ToString`, which obviously you can *override* in the actual type provided to `T`, but the compiler does not understand that you intended in some cases to give it an interface with its own `ToString` method, and thus won't call the method *through the interface*. The Mock object created by Moq creates an explicit implementation of `ToString`, and does not override the one inherited from `System.Object`, and thus you get the incorrect/unexpected result.

Comment: I see. When debugging I spent ages being confused about why this would be the case, but that does make sense. What a pain. Thanks for your help.